# Failed to collect dependencies at org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.4.0.Final:

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have a maven java project, it build correctly, but after add following dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
   <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject.app:myproject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.4.0.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.kie:kie-api:jar:6.4.0.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.dashboard-builder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.4.0.Final from/to jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I have imported certificate by InstallCert.java in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts

when I run: keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts
I can see following phrase in the cert.

---

```
*******************************************


Alias name: repository.jboss.org
Creation date: Jun 24, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=*.jboss.org, O=Red Hat Inc., L=Raleigh, ST=North Carolina, C=US
Issuer: C=SK, O="ESET, spol. s r. o.", CN=ESET SSL Filter CA
Serial number: bc5a03085090ce27714df01dd25ab4d
Valid from: Wed Jan 14 03:30:00 IRST 2015 until: Wed Jan 18 15:30:00 IRST 2017
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  4A:F0:5E:4D:60:E9:45:E3:7B:43:E7:37:9D:2E:98:7C
     SHA1: 21:CB:F8:4C:32:25:32:CE:70:E9:21:99:B5:D0:7D:C0:D9:4C:A5:62
     SHA256: 06:1D:1D:50:53:92:3D:20:A9:BD:CF:98:32:F6:B6:07:6A:95:2C:8C:F5:AE:F4:18:88:F6:2A:16:D4:EF:27:76
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.jboss.org
  DNSName: jboss.org
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5A 1E 3F C5 64 68 F4 C9   A2 77 51 B0 E8 EE 2A 13  Z.?.dh...wQ...*.
0010: D9 6C A1 D0                                        .l..
]
]



 *******************************************
 ******************************************
```

I then got restarted. But I am still getting the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a certificate to access JBoss Maven repo? It works in HTTP also http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/.

Comment: I really don't need it. my problem was solved by put 
     <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  in pom.xml . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

adding below to .m2/settings.xml should resolve :

```
<repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

if not then adding below config to your project POM should resolve issue:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```